# .NETCORE 2.0 AcquireTokenAsync throwing AdalServiceException: TaskCanceledException

Tags: .net-core, adal

I am using below code to fetch AAD token using 3.16 version of ADAL library on .DOTNET core 2.0 and consistently getting TaskCancelledException after 1 min. Even on retries this is happening.

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(auth);
if (authenticationContext == null)
throw (new ArgumentNullException("AuthenticationContext")); authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();
ClientAssertionCertificate clientAssertion = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(audience, clientAssertion).Result;
```

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (unknown_error: Unknown error) ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: unknown_error: Unknown error ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpClientWrapper.d__30.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__211.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__211.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__201.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__67.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__64.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__55.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__51.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at TestAADCallsForLinux.Program.FetchAADToken(String registeredObjectInfo) in C:\Users\risraj\source\repos\TestAADCallsForLinux\TestAADCallsForLinux\Program.cs:line 87 ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: unknown_error: Unknown error ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpClientWrapper.d__30.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__211.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__211.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalHttpClient.d__20`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__67.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__64.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__55.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__51.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__27.MoveNext()
>   ErrorCode: unknown_error
>   StatusCode: 0<---

Answer (score 0):

Could be a threading issue...You need to use the async/await pattern, otherwise you'll run into multi-threading issues. See the [wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/use-async-controller-actions) for more information.